# using WordNet to perform stemming, io error: Too many open files

Tags: java, io, nlp

I'm using [**WordNet**](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) to perform stemming on an input text file.

For an input with a small number of instances everything works fine but when I increase the number of input instances the programme crashes with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/WordNet-3.0/dict/index.adj (Too many open files)
```

I suppose I need to close something that is open but I'm not quite sure what, I tried implementing a solution in accordance with [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601634/too-many-open-files) question, trying to close the file being read in, but that didn't work. This leads me to belive it is more to do with WordNet, though I can't be certain.

I'm not very familiar with java io operations.

Perhaps someone more expert in this area might be able to point out where I have gone awry.

This is where I read the input file:

```
public void readFile( String input, 
                      Ontology ontology, 
                      List<Sentence> sentences, 
                      Map<String,List<Integer>> subject2index, 
                      Map<String,List<Integer>> object2index,
                      Set<String> joints) throws IOException 
{   
    // do what we came here to do, read the input
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( input ));

    //now that we're reading the file we need to send it on
    //to the regex extractot after we're through
    RegEx regex_extractor = new RegEx();

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        regex_extractor.match_regex_patterns(line, ontology, sentences, subject2index, object2index, joints);
    }
}
```

This is the WordNet component:

```
public WordNet() throws IOException
{ 
    // construct the URL to the Wordnet dictionary directory
    wnhome = System.getenv("WNHOME");
    path = wnhome + File.separator + "dict";
    url = new URL ("file", null , path );

    // construct the dictionary object and open it
    dict = new Dictionary ( url ) ;
    dict.open();
}

public String getStem(String word)
{
    WordnetStemmer stem =  new WordnetStemmer( dict );

    List<String> stemmed_words = stem.findStems(word,  POS.VERB);

    if ( !stemmed_words.isEmpty() )
        return stemmed_words.get(0);
    else
        return word;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡try this!

```
    // do what we came here to do, read the input
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( input ));

    try 
    {

        //now that we're reading the file we need to send it on
        //to the regex extractot after we're through
        RegEx regex_extractor = new RegEx();

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            regex_extractor.match_regex_patterns(line, ontology, sentences, subject2index, object2index, joints);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        // ...
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (br != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                br.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }
```